# Firefox about:config preferences in SWT Browser

Tags: firefox, browser, swt, xulrunner

An application I am currently working on uses the SWT tool-kit's Browser widget to display a Firefox/XULRunner browser. I would like to set custom user agent data in Firefox about:config preferences; how does one alter them when working with SWT browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really work with the SWT browser, but http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-swt-dev/msg06747.html seems to indicate there at least used to be an about:config in the SWT browser. Did you try it? What happened?

Also the SWT browser should have a profile named "eclipse" by default (it seems it's located at `C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Application Data\Mozilla\eclipse\`, see [mozilla support](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles#w_finding-your-profile-without-opening-firefox) for more info about profiles.

You should be able to edit prefs.js in there to set your preferences.